# How to set Servlet Context in Jersey Unit Test Framework 2.5

Tags: unit-testing, maven, servlets, jersey, jersey-2.0

I have two questions:

1) How do you set the servlet Context for a Unit Test that extends  `JerseyTest`.  From the research I've done, it seems that I have to create a `TestContainer` for a `TestFactory` and pass in an `AppDescriptor`, but that seems more complicated then it should be.  Is there any other suggestions out there?

In general, looking for a way to set the Servlet Context in a unit test of my Jersey Resource Class which is done normally by the web.xml.

Example:

```
@Path(value = "/service")
public class Foo{

@Context ServletContext ctx;

@GET
@Path(value="/list")
public String list() {
    Controller ctrl = new Controller();
    ctx.setAttribute("controller", ctrl);
    return ctrl.getList();
}

}

public class FooUnitTest extends JerseyTest
{
    @Test
    public void testService()
    {

         //set/how to configure the context?
    }
}
```

The goal is to mock out the Controller so I can pass it into the context.

2) What's the difference between using the jersey test from the

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey.jersey-test-framework</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-grizzly</artifactId>
    <version>1.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

vs.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-bundle</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

This is Jersey framework 2.5

Comment: Not sure why points were minus off for formatting.  Unless you have a valid solution

Answer (score -2):

You can use `org.springframework.mock.web.MockServletContext` class to mock servlet context. It's a part of Spring framework.

[MockServletContext](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mock/web/MockServletContext.html)

Comment: The question is not Spring-specific, so this is not a good solution in general.